# How do I get checkboxes to bind to boolean values in my data model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've browsed similar questions for a couple hours, but haven't come up with anything that's an exact match. What I want to do is have a checkbox be automatically checked via data binding to a true/false value in my data. I can get the item names to load no problem, and I can even pull the checkbox values later on for saving to the server, but I can't get the initial values to load properly.

Here's a reduced example that shows the fundamental problem; HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="shoppingListNg.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
<div ng-controller="ShoppingListCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in shoppingList">
            <td>
                <div>{{item.text}}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isGotten" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
function ShoppingListCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.shoppingList = [
      {
      "text": "V8 fusion",
      "isGotten": "true"
      }, 
      {
      "text": "Whole milk container",
      "isGotten": "false"
      },
      {
      "text": "Protein bars",
      "isGotten": "true"
      }
   ];
};
```

Any idea why I can't get those checkboxes to respect the "true" and "false" values in the model? They always show unchecked whenever the page loads. Do I need to use ng-checked or a different directive?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that you have "true" and "false" in quotes, which makes them strings instead of booleans that Angular can bind the checkbox to.

If you just remove the quotes as follows, your code then works correctly. A working example is at http://plnkr.co/edit/gkchmOBTkBtVv3TijlZW .

```
function ShoppingListCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.shoppingList = [
      {
      "text": "V8 fusion",
      "isGotten": true
      }, 
      {
      "text": "Whole milk container",
      "isGotten": false
      },
      {
      "text": "Protein bars",
      "isGotten": true
      }
   ];
};
```

Comment: But this does not work for radio buttons do you know how to do it for radio buttons

Answer (score 8):

I could only get ng-true-value working if I added the extra quotes like so (as shown in the official Angular docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

```
ng-true-value="'1'"
```

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your data you may not want pure true/false in your code.  AngularJS evaluates true/false and 1/0 booleans into strings anyway, so you may be better off using strings.

In this codepen I use "1" and "0" for boolean values, and ngTrueValue and ngFalseValue to tell AngularJS how to keep the bindings intact.  Very simple and clean.

Codepen here:  http://codepen.io/paulbhartzog/pen/kBhzn

Code snippet:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in list1" class="item" id="{{item.id}}">
  <strong>{{item.id}}</strong> <input name='obj1_data' type="checkbox" ng-model="list1[$index].data" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"> Click this to change data value below
</p>
<pre>{{list1 | json}}</pre>
```